# What is the initial value of a JavaScript function's prototype property?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I know that the `prototype` property of JavaScript function objects is copied to the internal `[[Prototype]]` property (a.k.a. `__proto__`) of objects instantiated by using the function as a constructor. So, I can set this property to any object that I want to act as the prototype:

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype = {
  toString: function() { return "I'm a Foo!"; }
}
new Foo().toString()
// --> "I'm a Foo!"
```

It seems that it is widespread practice to add functions that should act as class methods to the *existing* prototype of newly generated functions like this:

```
function Bar() {}
Bar.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "I'm a Bar!";
}
new Bar().toString()
// --> "I'm a Bar!"
```

It is unclear to me, though, what the *initial value* of the `prototype` property is.

```
function Baz() {}
Baz.prototype
// --> Baz {
//       constructor: function Baz() {},
//       __proto__: Object
//     }
```

The comment shows what Chrome's JavaScript console prints. Does this mean that every function that I create actually creates *two* objects? One for the function itself (the `constructor`) and one for its prototype?

Is this defined somewhere in the ECMAScript standard? I tried to find it but couldn't. Do all browsers handle this in the same way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The initial value of `prototype` on any newly-created `Function` instance is a new instance of `Object`, but with the own-property `constructor` set to point back to the new function.

This is described in typical ECMAScript-spec completely-unreadable fashion by ECMA262-5 in section 13.2:

> (16.) Let *proto* be the result of creating a new object as would be constructed by the expression `new Object()` where `Object` is the standard built-in constructor with that name
>
> (17.) Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *proto* with arguments "constructor", Property Descriptor
>   {[[Value]]: F, { [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true}, and false.
>
> (18.) Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of F with arguments "prototype", Property Descriptor {[[Value]]: `proto`, { [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false}, and false.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: OMG! I dive into the ECMAScript specification every now and then, but this is hardly readable. Do you know a resource that explains everything in it step by step (or at least explaining those horrific parts)?

Comment: Sadly no. It's a shame there is no good reference for ECMAScript as a language in actual English, especially as so many of its features are... to be generous... a bit quirky. We've got the vendor-specific guides like MDC, MSDN and Adobe, we've got the nigh-unusable ECMA spec (you do kind of get used to the above language, but it's still really heavy-going at the best of times), and apart from that there's the gutter of random tutorial sites that are full of errors and awful advice. And this, for one of the most widely-used languages in the world. It's hopeless.

Comment: Yeah, I know some of these horrible tutorials. So, the situation here is kind of the same as with [PHP tutorials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119083/php-tutorial-that-is-security-accuracy-and-maintainability-conscious)?

Comment: Heh. Perhaps not quite that bad, as most JS doesn't have the opportunity to fall victim to SQL injection (unless people start using Web SQL Database, anyway...) and not *all* tutorials use naïve `innerHTML` string hacking to drag in client-side XSS problems. Although I don't really like jQuery, its use has pushed idioms like binding from script (instead of event handler attributes) and inline function expressions, so that today's tutorials are at least less awful than the `eval` and `document.all`-filled tutorials of yesteryear.

Comment: You're right about that, but I still find `document.all` and the like in scripts written *today* (not to mention the copy-paste programmers who don't have the slightest idea how JavaScript really works).

Comment: Quite so. JavaScript in the wild today is only 95% bad, instead of 99% bad. Hooray for progress!