# What does 'is an instance of' mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object, instance

The answer to this question:
[What is the initial value of a JavaScript function's prototype property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073677/what-is-the-initial-value-of-a-javascript-functions-prototype-property)

has this sentence:

> The initial value of prototype on any newly-created Function instance is a new instance of Object

As far as I know, Javascript doesn't have classes and the word 'instance' therefor doesn't make sense in my head. How should one interpret 'instance' in Javascript?

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to put my question in the comment thread on that answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're right that JavaScript doesn't have classes (yet), but it does have constructor functions, an `instanceof` operator that defines a relationship between objects and constructors, and a form of inheritance based on prototype chains.

`obj instanceof ctor` is true when `ctor.prototype` is on `obj`'s prototype chain.

Modulo the caveat below, you could implement `instanceof` in EcmaScript 5 thus

```
function isInstanceOf(obj, ctor) {
  var proto = ctor.prototype;
  if (typeof obj === "object" || typeof obj === "function") {
    while (obj) {
      if (obj === proto) { return true; }
      obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Unless you go around reassigning prototypes (`o = new MyConstructor(); MyConstructor.prototype = somethingElse`) it should be the case that `new MyConstructor() instanceof MyConstructor`.

Section [15.3.5.3](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.5.3) explains this in detail.

> 15.3.5.3  `[[HasInstance]] (V)`
>
> Assume F is a Function object.
>
> When the [[HasInstance]] internal method of F is called with value V, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If V is not an object, return false.
> 2. Let O be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of F with property name "prototype".
> 3. If Type(O) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 4. Repeat
>
>    1. Let V be the value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of V.
>    2. If V is null, return false.
>    3. If O and V refer to the same object, return true.

This isn't the whole story because host objects (like DOM nodes) are allowed to implement the `[[HasInstance]]` internal method however they like but most browsers implement host objects to behave as closely to native objects as possible.

Comment: Dont says `(yet)` :( classes are still strawman. If we're lucky they wont get into ES6 !

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript does not have classes, but it does have Types.  You can define your own type and create a new instance using the `new` keyword:

```
function Foo(initialValue) {
    this.value = initialValue || 0;
}
var foo = new Foo(17);
var fooIsAFoo = foo instanceof Foo;  // true!
var fooIsAnObject = foo instanceof Object; // also true!  We have inheritance here :)
```

Comment: Can you back the concept of `Types` with references to the specification? I have a feeling there are only native types and `Foo` is not a type.

Answer (score 3):

In JS, a function is an Object. It takes a while to get used to that, but it is true. Throw that around for a bit and the code that you see others using will make sense more. If you have seen Javascript where people are passing a function(){} as a parameter to another function, that is proof that functions are first class objects.

Once you can wrap your head around that (it took me a while) then you need to understand that if you make a function, you can get a New instance of it. See the following code:

```
function FooName(){
    var name;
    this.setName = function(n){
        this.name = n;
    }
    this.getName = function(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
var n1 = new FooName();
var n2 = new FooName();
n1.setName("FOO");
n2.setName("BAR");
```

At this point you have two instances of the FooName method: n1 and n2. It is kind of a convention in JS to name your instantiable function with an Uppercase first letter, instead of the customer lowercase first letter. In this example, I indication that my function can be instanced by naming it FooName instead of fooName. I hope this makes sense.

In the example above, n1 has three properties. A private name property, a public setName property, and a public getName property. Each time I instantiate a new FooName, a copy of getName and setName are going to be created. That can waste space in memory. Since the getName and setName isn't going to change, I don't need a new copy of it for each FooName instance. This is where prototypes come in.

You can say the following, and then getName and setName will only exist once in memory, thus freeing up memory, which is a good thing.

```
FooName.prototype.setName = function(n){
    this.name = n;
}
FooName.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
}
```

If you remove the getName and setName from the FooName function, then now you will have a FooName "class" that has two methods, getName and setName.

Play with it. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Not sure if this answers @loldrup's question but it sure gave me some insight. Thanks +1

Comment: True... 
I guess I would say that "instanceof" means that you have a function, and have declared a new one of the. The key word "new" is what will get you the instance. Example, my my code above, var n3 = FooName is not the same as var n3 = new FooName. The difference in leaving the new out is VERY SIGNIFICANT. If you left the "new" out, then all of the uses of the word "this" would refer to the window itself. The "this" in JS refers to the context in which it is called. If you call it inside of an obj instance, it refers to the obj. If you call it outside of an obj instance, it's global.

Comment: "If you remove the getName and setName from the FooName function, then now you will have a FooName "class" that has two methods, getName and setName."

That is, the prototype object of the (function-)-object FooName now has these functions, and, because of the name resolution method that is able to follow prototype-chains, all instances of FooName will be able to find these methods. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript functions are first-class objects, that means you can treat them just like any object.

//Define class

```
   function User(name,age)
    {
        this.Name=name;
        this.Age=age
    }
```

//create insatnces

```
var user1= new User('Demo1','50');
var user2= new User('Demo2','100');


alert(user1.Name);
alert(user2.Name);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_prasad/hmUku/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't use classical inheritance, it uses [prototypal inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) where everything is an "Object" and inheritance is accomplished by cloning, for example:

```
var myPrototype = function() {
   var privateMember = "I am private";
   var publicMember = "I am public";
   var publicMethod = function () {
       alert(privateMember); 
   }
   return {
      publicMember = publicMember,
      publicMethod = publicMethod
   }
}

var myInstace = new myPrototype();
myInstance.publicMethod();
```

here `myInstance` can be said to be an "instance of" `myPrototype`, but in reality what happened is by using the `new` keyword you cloned `myPrototype` to create `myInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

So now I have fabricated a page describing what I think all you guys* are saying:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VvqqO2LMmilLbIvcU2JHI9ifaoMs-DB-farEzwuVuwM/edit?hl=da

illustrated with nice graphics :)

regards Jon

*and this link:
http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=Understanding_the_JavaScript_new_keyword

Answer (score -3):

Javascript is object-oriented, so it does have classes. There simply isn't an explicit "class" directive, like you would have in other OOP languages.

Comment: Javascript does not have classes, it is a prototype based language which is a different way of implementing OOP.  The differences might be subtle but they are important.