# is it possible to have a common variable between two self invoking functions

Tags: javascript

I have two self invoking functions and I need to have a variable which can be common between these two functions but not a global variable. One of functions setting value to the variable the other one uses it.

Answer (score 2):

what about having another function which will act as a getter and setter for that variable that you need, like this:::

```
function Value(){    
    var value = val;
    this.getValue = function(){
        return value;
    };
    this.setValue = function(val){
        value = val;
    };
}
```

and then you can use like this

```
 (function() {
    var variable = new Value();
    variable.setValue("value");
    variable.getValue();
})();
```

you read up more in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002486/what-does-is-an-instance-of-mean-in-javascript) which also add a clever way to clear up memory.

Comment: I like this approach, but would go one further and inject an instance of `Value` *into* the self-invoking function so that it can be mocked

Comment: @RGraham This is kind of embarrassing, im not sure what you mean mate :(

Comment: @jycr753 He means: `(function(variableService) { /* use it here */ })(variable)`.